# TypeError: this.setAttribute is not a function

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm new to d3 and reactjs. I was trying to make a bar chart with following Rect.js componenet

I've tried to debug right before `// enter-update` but with no avail.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as d3 from 'd3';

const dataset = [14, 68, 24500, 430, 19, 1000, 5555];
const width = 600;
const height = 400;



export default class Rect extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}

componentWillMount() {

}

componentDidMount() {
  this.renderRect();
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  this.renderRect();

}

renderRect() {
  this.container = d3.select(this.refs.container);


  // draw refs rectangle
  this.rects = this.container.selectAll("bar")
                            .data(dataset)
                            .enter();
  // exit
  this.rects.exit().remove();

  // enter-update
  this.rects = this.rects.enter()
                         .append("rect")
                         .merge(this.rects)
                         .attr("y", d => 24500 - d)
}

  render() {
    return (
      <svg ref="container" width={width} height={height}>

      </svg>
    )
  }
}
```

The error message is `TypeError: this.setAttribute is not a function`; When I debug, I found the error only appears when I have `attr` chained after `merge(this.rects)` but I don't understand why.

[image: setAttribute error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal example of the issue:

```
var rect = container.selectAll("rect")
  .data([1,2,3])
  .enter();   // return a selection of entered placeholders

var merge = rect.enter() // return a selection of entered placeholders
  .append("rect") // return a selection of appended nodes
  .merge(rect)    // merge appended nodes with entered placeholders.
  .attr("someAttribute",0); // set an attribute for both appended nodes and entered placeholders.
```

The issue is straightforward: the merged selection isn't what you think it is.

The selection `rect` is a selection of placeholder nodes created by `.enter()` - not actual nodes in the DOM. They have a few methods, but no method for setting attributes. This is why the above code, or your code, will produce the error: `this.setAttribute is not a function`, as `setAttribute` is not a method of an entered placeholder (see the source [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/enter.js)).

Instead we just drop the first .enter() statement. Which will also lead to the behavior you want, as we probably don't want `rect` to be an enter selection, since we do exit and update after. Instead we want `rect` to be a selection of existing `rect` elements, not placeholders. Modifying the above we get to account for this change we get:

```
var rect = container.selectAll("rect")
  .data([1,2,3])

rect.enter().append("rect").merge(rect)...

rect.exit()....
```

Or with your code:

```
  // draw refs rectangle
  this.rects = this.container.selectAll("bar")
      .data(dataset)
      // No enter here

  // exit
  this.rects.exit().remove();

  // enter-update
  this.rects = this.rects.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .merge(this.rects)
    .attr("y", d => 24500 - d)
```