# Missing rects in bar chart

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm new to react and d3. I'm trying our barChart but only see one overlapped rect. Examining each `rect` element, I see that `x, y, height and width` are expected. But I don't understand why the other 3 rect are not shown. 
[image: render single bar]

[image: html]

BarChart.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { scaleLinear } from 'd3-scale';
import { max } from 'd3-array';
import { select } from 'd3-selection';

export default class BarChart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.createBarChart()
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.createBarChart()
  }

  createBarChart = () => {
    const node = this.node
    const dataMax = max(this.props.data)
    const yScale = scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, dataMax])
    .range([0, this.props.size[1]])

    select(node)
    .selectAll('rect') 
    .data(this.props.data)
    .enter() // placeholder selection
    .append('rect') // return a selection of appended rects

    select(node)
    .selectAll('rect') // rect selection
    .data(this.props.data) // update data in rect selection
    .exit()
    .remove() // exit and remove rects

    select(node)
    .selectAll('rect') // rect selection
    .data(this.props.data) // join data with rect selection
    .style('fill', '#fe9922')
    .attr('x', (d, i) => i * 25)
    .attr('y', d => this.props.size[1] - yScale(d))
    .attr('height', d => yScale(d))
    .attr('width', 25)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // Pass a reference to the node for D3 to use
      <svg ref={node => this.node = node}
            width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height}
      >

      </svg>
    )
  }
}
```

With [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57315527/typeerror-this-setattribute-is-not-a-function), I've updated `createBarChart()` but still seeing the same odd rendering.

```js
  createBarChart = () => {
    const node = this.node
    const dataMax = max(this.props.data)
    const yScale = scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, dataMax])
    .range([0, this.props.size[1]])

    this.rects = select(node)
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(this.props.data)

    this.rects
    .exit()
    .remove()

    this.rects = this.rects.enter()
    .append('rect')
    .merge(this.rects)
    .style('fill', '#fe9922')
    .attr('x', (d, i) => i * 25)
    .attr('y', d => this.props.size[1] - yScale(d))
    .attr('height', d => yScale(d))
    .attr('width', 25)
  }
```

App.js

```js
        <div>
          <BarChart  data={[50,10,11,13]} size={[500,500]}/>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug, I passed in wrong props, `this.props.width` and `this.props.height` doesn't exist in this case. As height of my rect overflows the svg box, I can only see one longest bar, but not the other shorter ones.

```js
      <svg ref={node => this.node = node}
            width={this.props.size[0]} height={this.props.size[1]}
      >


      </svg>
```